# Python program write tuple filtered by a specific publisher name with process name, pid, path and launch arguments to a txt file

Tags: python, tuples, pid

This is what I wrote so far :)
I don't know how to filter the processes by the publisher to show only those processes and write them in a tuple to a txt file.

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()

for proc in c.Win32_Process ():
    a = proc.name
    b = proc.processId
    c = proc.executablepath
    my_tuple = (a, b, c)
    print(my_tuple)
```

The output for this program is:

```
('svchost.exe', 3584, None)
('svchost.exe', 3592, None)
('svchost.exe', 3608, None)
('svchost.exe', 3616, None)
('KiteService.exe', 3640, None)
('ProductAgentService.exe', 3700, None)
('svchost.exe', 3732, None)
('updatesrv.exe', 3768, None)
('vmtoolsd.exe', 3780, None)
('VGAuthService.exe', 3800, None)
('svchost.exe', 3792, None)
('svchost.exe', 3920, None)
('svchost.exe', 3492, None)
('svchost.exe', 4152, None)
('dllhost.exe', 4872, None)
('dllhost.exe', 5048, None)
('WmiPrvSE.exe', 3632, None)
('msdtc.exe', 5040, None)
('VSSVC.exe', 5404, None)
('svchost.exe', 5508, None)
('svchost.exe', 5688, None)
('svchost.exe', 5752, None)
('bdntwrk.exe', 5940, None)
('conhost.exe', 5960, None)
('sihost.exe', 6460, 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\sihost.exe')
('svchost.exe', 6516, 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\svchost.exe')
('svchost.exe', 6552, 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\svchost.exe')
('taskhostw.exe', 6820, 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\taskhostw.exe')
('svchost.exe', 6844, None)
('DiscoverySrv.exe', 6992, None)
('svchost.exe', 7040, None)
('ctfmon.exe', 7152, None)
('explorer.exe', 5416, 'C:\\WINDOWS\\Explorer.EXE')
('svchost.exe', 6620, None)
('svchost.exe', 6444, None)
('svchost.exe', 7120, None)
('svchost.exe', 7196, None)
('svchost.exe', 7324, None)
('svchost.exe', 7480, 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\svchost.exe')
('svchost.exe', 7924, None)
('StartMenuExperienceHost.exe', 8016, 'C:\\Windows\\SystemApps\\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\\StartMenuExperienceHost.exe')
('svchost.exe', 8036, None)
('svchost.exe', 8152, None)
('RuntimeBroker.exe', 4336, 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\RuntimeBroker.exe')
('SearchApp.exe', 5196, 
('py.exe', 4932, 'C:\\WINDOWS\\py.exe')
('python.exe', 3820, 'C:\\Users\\Marius\\anaconda3\\python.exe')
```

And the output file should be (**but it isn't**) something like (as tuple in a txt file):

```
('process.exe', 2368, 'c:\\path', ['settings/services/configs/config.json'])
...
```

Comment: `but it isn't` so what you got ? Also how can you hope a tuple of **3** values to be written as a tuple of **4** values ?

Comment: Please share the output. If the output is in the correct format, writing it to a csv file would be the next step, however it is still possible to write to a txt.

Comment: In the first pass, read the data into memory, and then sort it in the desired way in the second pass. You can, of course, sort immediately, but this is an additional complication.

Comment: @DapperDuck I've edited the post and added part of the output result as example, as the edit option didn't allow me to enter the entire (long) output as I got the error "It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details” for obvious reasons;

Comment: @bruno yes, the 4th value is not present in the program for an obvious reason: I don't know how to translate the code for the launch arguments the process was launched based on;

Comment: apparently `wmic process where "name='bdservicehost.exe'" get commandline /format:list` doesn't show the results as in **process explorer** it just outputs as none for this service that starts as a process.
In **process explorer** it is shown as `"C:\Program Files\Bitdefender\Bitdefender Security\bdservicehost.exe" "settings/services/configs/bdshieldsrv_config.json"` so basically I need to find a command to work and give me that output as in **process explorer** and split them to just give me the launch arguments and not the path + launch arguments

Comment: so the fourth field is the list of args the program receive,  and in a lot of cases you do not get the path of the executable. You want what we have in a trivial way on Linux just looking under /proc

Comment: May be you get the expected data for the programs but not for the daemons ( the names can be the same for both so is confusing) ?

Comment: May I ask, where did you find the documentation for the ```proc.executablepath```? I was only able to find the documentation for the other two commands [here](https://github.com/tjguk/wmi/blob/master/docs/cookbook.rst).

Comment: @DapperDuck I found it here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process